# How to add css style to the all children of element at the same time?

Tags: jquery, css

Such as:

```
<div class="mostOut">
    <div class="a">
        <h3 class="b"></h3>
        <div class="d"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And how can I apply css style to the children of `"moustOut"` at the same time.E.g:

with one `click event`.the `css('opacity',1)` could apply to the `"a","b","d"` at the same time.Or ,exclude `"b"` .

Comment: Children can't have a greater opacity then their parent, why not set the opacity *only* on the `.mostOut` element?

Comment: because I am using a Jquery Ui and when I disable it .It apply disabled-state to the elements which it want.So I need to make opacity back to 1 for those elements.

Answer (score 10):

a little less code

```
$('.mostOut').click(function()
{
   $(this).children("*").css('opacity', 1);
});
```

and exclude ".b"

```
$('.mostOut').click(function()
{
   $(this).children("*").not(".b").css('opacity', 1);
});
```

or alternatively if its not the opacity causing the hidden/none

```
$('.mostOut').click(function()
{
   $(this).children("*").show();
});
```

Comment: the children() only find the next level of elements: such class="a",exclude the elements inside of "a"

Answer (score 2):

This might be a dirty solution, but it should work:

```
$('.mostOut').click(function()
{
  $(this).find('*').each(function()
  {
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);
  });
});
```

For excluding all but the `b` element, try this:

```
$('.mostOut').click(function()
{
  $(this).find('*').not('.b').each(function()
  {
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);
  });
});
```

Play with the code, as I just typed this off of the top of my head, so I'm not guaranteeing that it will work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**Have you considered using a 100% CSS method?**

As Nick Craver pointed out: "Children can't have a greater opacity then their parent, ***why not set the opacity only on the .mostOut element?***"

HTML

```
<div class="mostOut">
  div class mostOut
  <div class="a">
    div class a
    <h3 class="b">h3 class b</h3>
    <div class="d">div class d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mostOut{
  opacity:0.5;
}
.mostOut:active{
  opacity:1;
}
```

- [jsFiddle demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/RzGyA/)

Or, ***use the CSS Child Selector*** (same HTML as above):

CSS

```
.mostOut:active > div{
  border:solid 1px gray;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

- [jsFiddle demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/NxHJz/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use rgba to set opacity per element. Check out http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/